# What handles the navigation in the Hello, Lungo app?

Tags: javascript, html, lungo

I am working through the Lungo documentation<sup>1</sup> and the Hello, Lungo code<sup>2</sup> to learn the framework. The documentation says "The navigation in Lungo is entirely semantic, and you will use the element  or  and his data attribute “view-*” to tell the system which ,  or  you want to go to." But when I look at the Hello, Lungo code I don't see any `<a>` or `<button>` elements that move between the hello and main sections. What is handling this navigation? How does the application move between the sections?

<sup>1</sup> http://lungo.tapquo.com/documentation/#header
  <sup>2</sup> https://github.com/tomkruijsen/mwdapps/blob/master/hello_lungo/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it seems navigation on that example happens on form submit, and the handling code is in the app.js include at the bottom of the page ([line 27](https://github.com/tomkruijsen/mwdapps/blob/master/hello_lungo/index.html#L27)):

```
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
```

The [source of their demo app.js](https://github.com/tomkruijsen/mwdapps/blob/master/hello_lungo/app/app.js) is also on GitHub.